# Notifications not working with Android oneplus3 phone

Tags: android, oneplusthree

I have this function for notification generation.I have updated the code as per oreo requirements as well. What could be the issue here. Any help is appreciated.It is working on all the other phones.I have rechecked the settings for notifications as well

```
private void sendNotification(String messageTitle,String messageBody) {
        android.net.Uri sound;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0 /* request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        long[] pattern = {500, 500, 500, 500, 500};
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        SharedPreferences demoprefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("demo", MODE_PRIVATE);
        demiIsLoggedIn = demoprefs.getBoolean("demo", true);
        if (!demiIsLoggedIn)
            sound = defaultSoundUri;
        else
            sound = null;
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
                .setSmallIcon(getActivity().getApplicationInfo().icon)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1, 1)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";// The id of the channel.
            CharSequence name = "notification channel";// The user-visible name of the channel.
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        notificationManager.notify(12 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        Log.d("wajdan","oneplus");

    }
```

Comment: Did log work on the Oneplus?

Comment: yes I am getting the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `NotificationChannel` in notificationBuilder

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "my_channel_01")
...
```

Comment: I believe the 2-arg constructor is the new thing for NotificationCompat.Builder as discussed here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462666/notificationcompat-builder-deprecated-in-android-o

Comment: but It shows an error saying  " Builder (android.content.context) Builder cannot be applied to (class,java.lang.string)" , I am using the build tools 27.0.3, what to change now?

Comment: I edit answer try with getActivity().getApplicationContext()