# Why it Showing deprecated API usage in Notificationcompat.Builder

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, android-fragments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgaih.png)

IT showing API deprecated and my app does not support any lower android version i also provide the minSdk version is 19,still it does not support.Please give me any suggestion

Comment: Possibly it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462666/notificationcompat-builder-deprecated-in-android-o. Check it and confirm

Comment: And yes, check compile SDK version not minSdk version