# Custom Android notification with RemoteView and actions

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an issue for display a notification with a `RemoteViews` and add an action on it with `addAction(R.drawable.ic_notification, "More", pendingIntent)`

This is the notification with the remoteViews without the `addAction` method

[image]

This is the notification with the addAction

[image]

As you can see the system don't display the RemoteViews and display only the action button

This is the instanciation of the remoteViews

```
RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);
notificationLayout.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_small_iv, R.drawable.logo);
notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_small_title, remoteMessage.getData().get(TITLE));
notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_small_subtitle, remoteMessage.getData().get(CONTENT));
```

And this is the notification builder where I set the configuration and add Action

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.nice_blue))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1000, 1000)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL)
              .addAction( 0,"More", pendingIntent)
            .build();
```

This is how I create the pending Intent but I'm not sure is related

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

I'm pretty sure it's possible to have a custom view and a AddAction button because Slack have it on the Android application

Comment: Interesting question - your code works on an emulator running Oreo (one can see the custom View after expanding the Notification) but it does not work (like you describe) on an emulator running Lollipop.(I used androidx libraries - which libraries and classes do you use/ import?)

Comment: I have this problem on >= Oreo and Lolipop I can see the custom view on both versions and I use the android import like android.widget.RemoteViews and android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat but on both versions I have this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the same boat.  I wanted a custom view on top, with the options of the action buttons on the bottom.  What you're looking for is the `NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle.`

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408000/android-notification-with-decoratedcustomviewstyle)